# Do I need to leave a dead air space to insulate the walls of my shed?

Tags: insulation, shed

I am going to use 1" thick rigid foam to insulate the walls of a newly built 8' x 10' outdoor shed. My question is: do I press the rigid foam up next to the exterior wall or do I need to leave a dead air space? I am going to use bats to insulate the ceiling because it was built using 2 x 4' studs. The walls were built using 2 1/2" x 1 1/2" studs.

I'm going to use the shed for a small workshop, but I'm not going to put AC or Heat in it.

Comment: I'm not sure how much good insulation will do if you don't have any HVAC. Over time the inside will end up the same temperature as the outside. On the other hand, it would not take very much power to heat/cool a well-insulated shed of that size, and you would only need to run it when you want to use the shed.

Comment: We were thinking of adding HVAC but we are not savvy on doing that. I appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dead air space is not needed for insulation, the rigid foam insulation (if XPS, not EPS) forms a moisture barrier and thermal insulation. Additional batting can be added on the inside side of the foam.

If your shed has no sheathing but cladding only, the benefit of an air gap is that any moisture from rain can drip down behind the siding, and ensure that the siding, if wood, can ventilate and dry from behind.

A clarification on sheathing and cladding:

Sheathing is hard panel material for floor, wall and roof, e.g plywood/OSB. Cladding is siding for appearance and weather resistance. Most homes have sheathing attached to studs, on the exterior side of walls, then a rain barrier (breathable plastic or black paper), and then the cladding, a.k.a siding. This leaves the joist space free for insulation and accessible from the inside.

Sheathing panels provide shear strength to the structure, but in small sheds cladding can also be used for such strengthening. An example is cedar bevel (lapped) siding that is fastened to the studs and rims, without further sheathing behind it. Often a diagonal shear strip is then mounted across the studs, on the inside of the shed.

Comment: "Sheathing" would be a vapor barrier type material, while "cladding" would be a siding material, correct?

Comment: @FreeMan In NA-parlance, sheathing is hard panel material for floor, wall and roof, e.g plywood/OSB. Cladding is siding for appearance and weather resistance. In the UK I imagine cladding has to do with knights and kings...

Comment: Ah, so my shed with T1-11 panels over studs has wall sheathing and cladding all in one. Thanks for the clarification.